# Create a module with submodules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a small homebrewed framework. I'm using this in several projects and I would like to bring that in a handy format for reusing it.

I would like to organize the code as follows:

- Each prototype has its own file
- Each file is a require.js module
- I would like to combine all files together in one file for shipping.

I have used r.js to combine all files together in one, but how can I load the modules with require(...) from another js-file which is not part of the combined file? Or more detailed, I would like to use the modules from the combined file in another app which has its own modules.

I mean, require.js expects only one module per file and now I have n modules in one file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is what the `bundles` option is for. Taking an example from [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles):

```
bundles: {
    'primary': ['main', 'util', 'text', 'text!template.html'],
    'secondary': ['text!secondary.html']
}
```

With this when if you require `main` from outside the bundle, and `main` is not yet loaded, then RequireJS will know that it will find the module `main` in the same place where the module `primary` is located.

Comment: Is it possible to export that bundle-config as a part of the optimized and combined js-file that is created by r.js? That would disburden the bundles user from defining that config by him/herself. Otherwise the bundle-user must know its contents.

Comment: Some months ago I've had the problem of having to generate such a list for one of my projects, I've had to do it in a semi-manual way. (My solution is unfortunately not a general one.) I do not know a way to generate it automatically.

Comment: As the author of the bundle I can write that manually in my case. But I don't want that the user of the bundle (who might be someone else) has to do that. So it would be nice if I could define the bundle in the bundle itselfe, so that the user could directly use the moduleIds from the bundle.